# Representation of an oriented manifold as a set of common zeroes of smooth functions

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

Let $M$ be an arbitrary oriented smooth manifold of dimension $m$. Is it always diffeomorphic to a sumbanifold in ${\mathbb R}^n$ (with some $n$) defined as a set $X$ of common zeroes of $n-m$ smooth functions $f_1,...,f_{n-m}$ (defined on an open set $U\subseteq {\mathbb R}^n$ and having linearly independent differentials in each point $x\in X$: $df_1(x)\wedge...\wedge df_{n-m}(x ) \ne 0$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had such functions then the tangent bundle of the manifold would be stably trivial, which is not always the case.  The lowest dimension where there is a countexample is 4.  Thus, $\mathbb{CP}^2$ can indeed be embedded in Euclidean space, as can any compact manifold, but its tangent bundle is not stably trivial, in the sense that one cannot add a trivial bundle to the tangent bundle to get another trivial bundle.  This follows from characteristic class theory, see e.g. the classic text Milnor, Stasheff, Characteristic classes.

I am not sure what level text you are studying now, so I would add that the gradient vector fields of your functions $f_i$ would give a trivialisation of the normal bundle of the submanifold, and the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^n$ gives a trivialisation of the sum of the tangent bundle and the normal bundle.

See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387373/chern-classes-tangent-bundle-mathbbcpn) for a discussion of chern classes of complex projective spaces.

Comment: Is ${\mathbb C}{\mathbb P}^2$ orientable?

Comment: Yes.  Moreover it is simply connected ($\pi_1(\mathbb{CP}^2)=0$).

Comment: Interesting... Which book do you recommend? Milnor-Stasheff?

Comment: Dear user72694, I think the lowest dimension for a counterexample is $2$, not $4$. Indeed the Stiefel-Whitney  class ot the tangent bundle to $\mathbb R \mathbb P^2$ is $1+x+x^2$, so that this tangent bundle cannot be stably trivial.

Comment: Those manifolds, which can be represented as zeroes of $f_i$ like I described, do they have special name?

Comment: Dear Sergei, they might be called (local) complete intersections.

Comment: Georges, thank you. Milnor-Stasheff seem to don't discuss ${\mathbb CP}^n$?.. And I didn't understand your explanation about ${\mathbb RP}^2$... this is a non-orientable manifold, isn't it?

Comment: Complex projective spaces are discussed on pages 159-161 in Milnor--Stasheff, as well as pages 169-170 and 177-178.